# HTML input type number, getting value

Tags: javascript, html

Hi i'm working on shop for a project of mine, and currently having some trouble setting prices for buying multiple items. what i am having trouble with is updating a price prediction off how many the player wants to buy. and i cant figure out of to get the current number, so i can use it to multiply the price

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <td align="left">Owned: 25
    <?php echo number_format($buildings['mine']); ?>
  </td>
  <td align="right" valign="bottom">Amount: <input type="number" name="house" min="0" max="100000" /><input type="submit" name="buy" value="Buy" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
  Cost: <?php echo number_format($buildings['mine']) * 5000 * 0.05 + 5000; ?>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: If you want to calculate the value while in the browser and without posting back to the server then you need to do all of your calculations in JavaScript and not PHP. If you don't plan to calculate totals unless the data is posted to the server then PHP is fine.

Comment: the data inst being sent back to the server, i do need to get the current number of building the user has from the server to do the calculations

Answer (score 0):

i did manage a solution its a little crude, doesnt update right away but it still work the way i need it to

```js
var output1 = document.getElementsByName("OUTPUT1")[0];

function changeInput(e) {
  // fill tolhouse with php
  var tolhouse = 1;
  //Calculate current price based on how many owned + price increse
  var curprice = (input1.value * ((tolhouse * 25000) * 0.05) + 25000);
   //calc predicted prices based off curpice + price incease
  var calc = input1.value * curprice + (input1.value * curprice * 0.05);
  output1.value = calc;
}

input1.onchange = changeInput;
```

```html
<form name="TESTING">
  <table border="1" width="600" height="200" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="3">
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2">
        <h1>TESTING</h1>
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <h3>INPUT</h3>
      </th>
      <th>
        <h3>OUTPUT</h3>
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <td><input type="number" name="INPUT1" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="OUTPUT1"></td>
    <table>
```